# largest and smallest number. python

Tags: python

I know it's pretty simple but im having a hard time finding the largest and smallest number out of three numbers in python.
Here is my code:
*** im not allowed to use the built in functions min and max so i have to use if and else...)***

```
def largest_and_smallest(number1, number2, number3):
    if number1 >= number2:
        maxn=number1
        minn=number2
        if number1 >= number3:
           maxn=number1
            if number3>=number2:
                minn=number2
            else:
                minn=number3
        else:
            maxn=number3
            minn=number2
    else:
        maxn=number2
        minn=number1
        if number2 >= number3:
             maxn=number2
             if number3 >= number2:
                 minn=number2
             else:
                 minn=number3
         else:
             maxn=number3
             minn=number1
    print(maxn,minn)
```

i get several of error messages such as: local variable maxn and minn are not used and also shadow name minn and maxn from outer scope. im pretty new to this so i would love to get some help. 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you unable to just use the built-in min() and max() functions? You could put the 3 number in a list and then use those. E.g. max([number1,number2,number3])

Comment: Please, specify what problems / errors you are observing. Don't ask people to solve homeworks for you.

Comment: Your code runs well for me. Those messages are actually warnings, not errors.

Comment: I have written which error messages python gave me. I didnt ask you to solve my homework,i wanted to know what was my mistake because to me the code seems fine

Comment: Mentioning just error messages without the information where they're actually thrown is useless. Add to your question exact errors including the positions where they're thrown, please.

Comment: Alright.  I'll  know  better for next time. Thank-you.

Answer (score 2):

Other than minor indentation problems which I'm sure were introduced when you pasted the code into your question, your code *works*. The "errors" you're getting aren't errors; they're warnings from your IDE and you can safely ignore them.

Comment: Thanks! It finally  worked..

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).

```
def sort3(a, b, c):
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    if b < a: a, b = b, a
    if c < b: b, c = c, b
    return a, b, c

# demo

data = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 3, 2),
    (2, 1, 3),
    (2, 3, 1),
    (3, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 1),
]

for row in data:
    print(sort3(*row))
```

**output**

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

---

As Simon mentions in the comments, my `sort3` function isn't written in the usual Python style. Here it is in PEP-0008 compliant form.

```
def sort3(a, b, c):
    """ Sort (a, b, c) using a Sorting Network """
    if c < b: 
        b, c = c, b
    if b < a: 
        a, b = b, a
    if c < b: 
        b, c = c, b
    return a, b, c
```

Comment: Impressive, but why do you put the content of the if statement on the same line as the statement?

Comment: @Simon Mostly to make it more compact. I don't normally do that, but I think it's actually more readable in this situation (and I wrote that code a few years ago). But I guess I ought to do it properly so as to not teach people bad habits. :)

Comment: Well still a very good answer, well played sir!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
def largest_and_smallest(number1, number2, number3):
    print(max([number1, number2, number3]))
    print(min([number1, number2, number3]))

largest_and_smallest(1, 3, 2)
```

Option 2: WIth list:

```
def largest_and_smallest(lst):
    print(max(lst))
    print(min(lst))


largest_and_smallest([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: The OP is not supposed to use built-ins, and you haven't said anything about his code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def largest_and_smallest(number1, number2, number3):
    if number1 > number2 and number1 > number3:
        maxn=number1
    elif number2 > number1 and number2 > number3:
        maxn=number2
    else:
        maxn=number3
    if number1 < number2 and number1 < number3:
        minn=number1
    elif number2 < number1 and number2 < number3:
        minn=number2
    else:
        minn=number3
    print maxn,minn


largest_and_smallest(1,2,3)
```

Comment: thanks. im not allowed to use them...

Comment: I edited the ans. do check it.

Comment: Thanks Karan. Thats obviously a shorter and probably better way to solve this but i still would like to know what was wrong with my code... It was longer than yours but i still used the same principles...

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code. its working just fine on my machine. there were just some indentation problems.

Comment: please upvote if it solves your problem. happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always 3 integers being submitted then I just sort a list and use the first and last index. **Since you are not allowed to use min and max** I'm using **sorted**

```
def largest_and_smallest(number1, number2, number3):
    arr = sorted([number1, number2, number3])
    n_min, n_mid, n_max = arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]
    return n_min, n_max
```

modding my answer to meed conditional requirements

```
def largest_and_smallest(number1, number2, number3):
    high = 0
    low = 0
    if (number1 > number2) and (number1 > number3):
        high = number1
    elif (number2 > number1) and (number2 > number3):
       high = number2
    else:
       high = number3

    if (number1 < number2) and (number1 < number3):
        low = number1
    elif (number2 < number1) and (number2 < number3):
       low = number2
    else:
       low = number3

    print(low, high)

largest_and_smallest(10, 100, 1)
largest_and_smallest(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: thanks. we haven't learned arrays yet so im only allowed to use if and else in my code...

Comment: Curious, why all the solutions just a minus 1?  If it was the OP that's not a great why to get the community to help you. So i'm going to plus 1 everything, because all the answers were valid, if not to your professors requirements.  So instead of asking us to do HW for you, provide an error message.

Comment: Courtesy returned ;-)

Comment: i didnt mark the answers as minus...

Comment: lol that's why I used an if conditional in my statement :-)

Comment: The OP is not supposed to use built-ins, and you haven't said anything about his code.

Comment: @reticentroot - Please ___do not___ use upvotes to cancel out downvotes.

Comment: @honza_p - Please ___do not___ engage in "you upvote me, I upvote you."

Comment: Yes, @TigerhawkT3 you are correct I apologize.

Comment: FWIW, the OP doesn't have enough rep to upvote (15 points), they certainly don't have enough rep to downvote (125 points). See  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: You don't need `arr`. You can just do `n_min, n_mid, n_max = sorted([number1, number2, number3])`

Comment: Your right, the arr was for demonstration purposes as it is not as intuitive to new programmers that python can unpack variables that way.

Comment: @TIgerhawkT3 ok

Answer (score 0):

Store them in list to make it easier on yourself and then use the built in Python functions to extract the min and max.

```
nums = [1,3,2]

print(max(nums))
print(min(nums))

> 3
> 1
```

[Built in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

[List, Arrays, and Other Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Edit: I saw that you're not allows to use built in functions, this will return a tuple of (min, max) based on an array of values.

```
nums = range(1,100)

def min_max(vals):
  min_val = vals[0]
  max_val = vals[0]

  for v in vals:
    if v > max_val:
      max_val = v
    if v < min_val:
      min_val = v

  return (min_val, max_val)

print(min_max(nums))
```

Comment: The OP is not supposed to use built-ins, and you haven't said anything about his code.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that wasn't apart of the initial requirements, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could make it more dense as well, increasing readability and still following usual python conventions, and way not expand it to allow for arbitrary many integers..

```
def min_and_max(numbers):
    min_num, max_num, *_ = numbers
    for num in numbers:
        max_num = num if num > max_num else max_num
        min_num = num if num < min_num else min_num
    return min_num, max_num


def main():
    data = (
        (1, 2, 3),
        (-20, 5, 100),
        (4, 23, 2, 3, 1),
        (123, -200, 3, 232),
        (123, 123, 123),
        (13, 21, 31, 1, 1, 1, 0)
    )
    for nums in data:
        print(min_and_max(nums))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

gives:

```
(1, 3)
(-20, 100)
(1, 23)
(-200, 232)
(123, 123)
(0, 31)
```

---

If you are not allowed to use list or such, well then, use the why python handles arguments, surely your teachers don't what you to change python.

You can simply tell python to not unpack the arguments you summit, and instead keep them in form that was inputed.

```
def min_and_max(*args):
    min_num, max_num, *_ = args
    for num in args:
        max_num = num if num > max_num else max_num
        min_num = num if num < min_num else min_num
    return min_num, max_num


def main():
    data = (
        (1, 2, 3),
        (-20, 5, 100),
        (4, 23, 2, 3, 1),
        (123, -200, 3, 232),
        (123, 123, 123),
        (13, 21, 31, 1, 1, 1, 0)
    )
    for nums in data:
        print(min_and_max(*nums))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

An issue is the maxn and minn are not defined in the scope, try inserting these lines I your code to initialize the maxn and minn variables:

```
maxn=0
minn=0
```

So now you code looks like this:

```
def largest_and_smallest(number1, number2, number3): 

    #initializing vars to zero
    maxn=0
    minn=0

    if number1 >= number2: 
         maxn=number1
         #rest of you code...
```

That should fix the local variable warning, for more information on scope consult the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html)

Comment: Those errors are not errors.

Comment: My bad, they are **warnings**, I updated my post